Can Ubuntu running on a Intel 12th gen based CPU x64 system be configured as an PCIe Endpoint
We are working on making two Intel 12th gen based Single board computers running Ubuntu to communicate on PCIe Interface.
So it is possible to configure one SBC x64 system as Endpoint to support ingress translation with another SBC x64 system (Root complex)
Regards,
Sujan
